# Lambda function in NodeJS that can be used to execute the transaction of buying a recipe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, react-native, aws-lambda

I attached the question in the picture below. I am not sure how to get started or solve this problem. How do I specifically access the params '{itemID, sellerID, buyerID}' and how do I add Global requirements?

[image: picture of question]

Comment: Someone will skip your question because they don't want to open your image.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the params using event object like event.payload the event object will be available in function arguments, take a look into example code bellow.

Reference for [AWS DynamoDb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-examples.html) Documents

```
/** Global requirements **/
/** Import statements for application dependencies **/            
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
        
         
        /** Function declaration **/
        exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
        
        /** get the payload **/
        const payload = event.payload;
        
        /** from payload take incoming post request body **/
        const itemId = payload.itemId;
        const sellerId = payload.sellerId;
        const buyerId = payload.buyerId;
        
        // add the other logic to update the db
        
        
        }
```